# Are parallelStreams on OneToMany collections safe?

Tags: java, jpa, java-stream, thread-safety

Presently just to be on the safe side, I have only used `stream()` for the collections classes defined by `@OneToMany` but I was wondering if using `parallelStream()` for some of the more complex filtering and reducing operations would be safe in a JPA context?