# Are Spliterators from Iterable results from Spring JPA safe to use in parallelStream

Tags: java, spring, jpa, java-stream, thread-safety

Similar to [Are parallelStreams on OneToMany collections safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63469182/are-parallelstreams-on-onetomany-collections-safe) but my question is specific to the result from a Spring JPA Repository query e.g.

```
public interface Students extends JpaRepository<Student, UUID> {
    @EntityGraph("Student.withProgramAndSchedule")
    @Query("from Student s")
    Iterable<Student> findAllWithProgramAndSchedule();
}
```

Can I safely use it with parallel? e.g.

```
StreamSupport.stream(students.findAllWithProgramAndSchedule().spliterator(), true)
```

Comment: You will rarely find thread safe spliterators. They key about this API is that they don’t need to be thread safe, the client code, i.e. the Stream API, has to use it in a thread safe way. This is done by accessing a single spliterator only by one thread and request the creation of another spliterator instance via `trySplit` for each additional worker thread.

Comment: based on your comment, wouldn't that mean if Spring JPA/Hibernate does things correctly the trySplit will not split even if it is parallel?  That being the case setting it to parallel = true would still be okay but it just won't do anything?

Comment: That’s not a matter of correctness. The class `AbstractSpliterator`, which will also be involved when not implementing `spliterator()` yourself, will provide an implementation that buffers elements into an array, allowing limited parallel support without accessing the spliterator’s state concurrently. Likewise, even when the source spliterator does not support splitting, returning `null`, stream operations like `sort` may buffer all element, sort in parallel, followed by full parallel processing for subsequent operations, as the sorted buffer has perfect splitting support.

Comment: So does that mean I should be able to just run parallelStream() on these collections with no issue?

Comment: It depends on the entities. I don’t know how Spring handles them, I’m not using it. If these entities are wrappers around a database connection and can not be used concurrently, you must not use parallel streams. As I tried to explain, a denying `trySplit` can not prevent parallel processing. But if these objects behave like POJOs, i.e. do not have interference when different objects are processed by different threads, then, you can use parallel streams without problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPA entity managers and the entities they manage are not thread safe.

One way to think about it is that `students.findAllWithProgramAndSchedule()` might trigger a lazy load. Under the hood this will use a JDBC connection which itself is not thread safe, therefore the `students.findAllWithProgramAndSchedule()` can't be thread safe.

Comment: I can confirm this to be correct with a very large dataset.  It appears it isn't possible to use parrallelStreams at all when JPA is involved.